# R - how to execute certain blocks of code based on a set of conditions without using functions?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, block

this might be a really fundamental question but im struggling to find a straight answer.
I have a certain criteria at the start of my script that would involve executing certain blocks of code dependent on some conditions with A and B being certain blocks of code.

If Condition 1 is true. Run A+B

If Condition 2 is true. Run A

If Condition 3 is true. Run B

The conditions above will be setup so that only one of the three will be true.
I have considered making A and B into separate functions (that dont have input arguements and just run whats in that block) but from searching I believe that it isnt best practice to do that. Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks

Edit - adding the info that I would only like to maintain code blocks A and B as one entity. I.e. not have to maintain multiple copies of A and B throughout the script using loops.

Comment: I believe that you can just use `if` conditions with blocks (or `if` and `elseif`), no need for functions.

Comment: Sorry Mike I didnt ask the question correctly so I have added more info. I essentially only want to have to maintain a single copy of each code block. So if I were to use if and elseif statements that I would have multiple copies of the code blocks A and B in the script if you understand what I mean.

Comment: Maybe make your code blocks functions? Could you include reproducible examples of your code blocks in the question?

Comment: @BarneyOnion, I think that it would still work -- tried writing out the pseudocode below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above, I think that you can use blocks based on the condition, assuming you set the variable `cond` to 1, 2, or 3 (corresponding to above), I think that you should be able to do the following without needing to either maintain code for A & B more than once or use functions using the pseudocode below:

```
if(cond == 1 | cond == 2) {
   RUN CODE A HERE
}
if(cond == 1 | cond == 3) {
   RUN CODE B HERE
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, it is possible to do it using logic like this. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No problem -- I'm glad that it worked!!! Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Done - as a new user I wasnt sure how to do that so I had to look it up. Thanks again.